# "Sehr geehrte Dame, sehr geehrter Herr" bei Anschreiben für Wohnung

Tags: grammatical-number, salutation

Es geht um eine Zeitungsannonce (auf die man online antworten kann) von einer Privatperson, von der ich den Namen nicht weiß. Die Anrede im Plural zu formulieren kommt mir komisch vor, da ich fast sicher sein kann, dass nur eine Person es lesen wird. "Sehr geehrte Dame, sehr geehrter Herr" kommt mir aber auch ganz grundsätzlich komisch vor. Ich habe eine derartige Formulierung noch nie gesehen.

Wie löse ich am besten dieses Dilemma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren, ...` ist die allgemeinste Form der Briefanrede und wird nur verwendet, wenn der konkrete Name des Ansprechpartners nicht bekannt ist. Grundsätzlich **falsch ist das nicht** – aber, wie du schon erkannt hast, etwas sperrig!

Diese förmlich korrekte Anrede endet übrigens immer mit einem Komma. Nach der Leerzeile wird dann das erste Wort des Einleitungssatzes klein geschrieben - sofern es sich natürlich nicht um ein Substantiv handeln.

Die bei Bewerbungen auf eine Stellenanzeige ohne Ansprechpartner oft vorgeschlagene Methode der Recherche nach dem richtigen Anredenamen wird bei der Zeitungsannonce versagen.

Ein paar Vorschläge - aber entscheiden musst du selbst:

> Guten Tag, ...
>
> Sehr geehrte Vermietende, ...
>
> Sehr geehrte Vermieterin, sehr geehrter Vermieter, ...

Comment: Auch wenn Vermieter, was die Anrede angeht, Kummer gewohnt sind, würde ich von "Guten Tag," ohne eine weitere Anrede absehen. Das wirkt (im Vergleich zu den anderen Anreden) sehr kurz angebunden und unpersönlich.

Comment: Da die Vermietung nur geplant ist, ist "Vermietende" falsch.

Comment: "Nach der Leerzeile wird dann das erste Wort des Einleitungssatzes klein geschrieben" - und zwar genau deshalb, weil es nicht das erste Wort jenes Satzes ist und der Satz eigentlich bereits mit der Anrede beginnt ;)